# Can we use a OS user other than "rundeck" to install rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

We have a use case where we cant use "rundeck" os user and need an alternative user to install rundeck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) three options:

1. If you need to execute your commands and/or script as another user you can use [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution) plugin, just save the latest release [.jar](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution/releases/download/1.0.5-SNAPSHOT/sudo-local-execution-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar) file in the `libext` [directory](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html#installation) and the plugin should be ready to use.
2. If you really need to run rundeck as another user, the easiest way is to make a [WAR-based installation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/jar.html#installing-as-an-executable-war). In this way, the user that launches rundeck is the "rundeck" user.
3. Run Rundeck on Docker, you can create a server-independent container based on the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck/), [here](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo) a lot of examples.